# Modifying android notfication formatting with GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using a Rails backend to send push notification to my android app users using GCM. I got it all working great but now I am wondering how to format the message better. I have seen push notification from other apps before with extra images and different font colors. Does anyone know how this could be implemented with GCM?

Also my app icon in the notification is very small. Is there anyway to make it a bigger size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really related to GCM. GCM only serves to pass the data you are going to display in the notification. How the notification looks is related only to Android notifications.

If you want to control the layout of the notification, you have several options :

- Custom Notifications - this is the way to go it you are targeting your app for older Android versions.

  You do it by defining a layout resource, creating a view using that layout and connecting the view to the notification. For example :

  ```
  Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_image, title, System.currentTimeMillis());
  notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
  RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
  contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.notification_image);
  contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title);
  contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, message);
  notification.contentView = contentView;
  ```

  Note that this method doesn't change the total area occupied by the notification on the screen, so if, for example, you use a large font, you won't have room for many characters.
- Newer Android versions (API level 16) have [Notification.BigTextStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigTextStyle.html) for generating large-format notifications that include a lot of text and [Notification.BigPictureStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle.html) for generating large-format notifications that include a large image attachment.
- Another option is to use [NotificationCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html) classes that enable you to use some of the newer notification features in lower API levels.

Comment: Hey, Thanks. This puts me in the right direction at least. I'm using Phonegap to build the apps and a plugin for it to setup notifications. So I will have to find a solution for that. At least I know now I have to work with Phonegap and not GCM.